# The conversion of the nvarchar value overflowed an int column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Previously I was using auto generated temp table but in one scenario I was getting this error:

> The conversion of the nvarchar value '182681000422' overflowed an int column

So I created a temp  table and I defined each column manually like this

```
Begin
    Drop Table #tmpSTDistData
End 

create table #tmpSTDistData
(
    DistRawProdIdentifier Varchar(50)
)
```

And if the value of `RawProductIdentifier` (data type `int`) in table 1 is NULL it will get from table 2 and its value is `TranslationCriteria2` (data type `varchar` here). Still I am getting same error.

```
INSERT INTO #tmpSTDistData
    SELECT
        DistRawProdIdentifier = (CASE ISNULL(dist.RawProductIdentifier, 0) 
                                    WHEN 0 
                                       THEN CAST(tm.TranslationCriteria2 as NVARCHAR(50)) 
                                       ELSE 0 
                                 END)
```

Comment: You have a problem with the `CASE` expression: all paths of the `CASE` must return the **same datatype** , and since you're not doing that (once returning an `int`, once a `nvarchar(50)`), then SQL Server will convert one of the return values to the datatype with the higher precedence. Since `int` has a higher precedence than `nvarchar`, your `nvarchar` string with the extra long value will be converted to `int` - and fail in the process.

Comment: I am using sql server

Answer (score 6):

You have a problem with the `CASE` expression: all paths of the `CASE` must return the **same datatype** (since `CASE` is an expression that returns **one single, atomic value** of one given datatype).

Since you're not doing that (once you're returning an `int`, once you have a `nvarchar(50)`), then SQL Server will convert one of the return values to the datatype with the **higher precedence** (see [MSDN on Data Type Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) for details).

Since `int` has a higher precedence than `nvarchar`, your `nvarchar` string with the extra long value will be converted to `int` - and fail in the process.

Depending on what **version** of SQL Server you're using, you might be able to use the `TRY_CAST` function (introduced in SQL Server **2012**):

```
SELECT   
    TRY_CAST('182681000422' AS INT)
```

which will return a `NULL` if the `CAST` fails (not an error message)

**Update:** since you're using SQL Server **2005**, you might want to either use `BIGINT` (instead of `INT`) which would be able to hold that value, or then return `VARCHAR(50)` from your `CASE` expression in both cases - like this:

```
DistRawProdIdentifier = 
    (CASE ISNULL(dist.RawProductIdentifier, 0) 
        WHEN 0 
           THEN CAST(tm.TranslationCriteria2 AS VARCHAR(50)) 
           ELSE CAST(0 AS VARCHAR(50))
     END)
```

You don't need to `CAST` the value you're using in the `ISNULL` - you need to cast the **return value** for the `CASE` in your `ELSE` branch ...

Comment: I understood your statement and I tried to convert both time as Varchar like below
DistRawProdIdentifier =(CASE ISNULL(CAST(dist.RawProductIdentifier as VARCHAR(50)), 0) WHEN 0 then CAST(tm.TranslationCriteria2 as VARCHAR(50)) else 0 end),

But same result. If you have any suggestion please update.

Comment: Thanks @marc_s but I am using sql server 2005. Please suggest any alternate solution

Comment: **Upgrade!!** SQL Server 2005 is dead - it's out of mainstream *and* extended support - upgrade so that you're not being left behind!